# Como puedo bloquear el evento pellizco o pinch

Tags: javascript

Buenas he desarrollado una web informativa  para un kiosko en un servidor linux, estoy intentando des habilitar el pellizco o 'pinch' puesto que descontrola la web en tamaño o zoom. He probado con javascript, jquery y hummer.js pero solo he conseguido que se des habilite todos los eventos táctiles.

Hay forma de bloquear solo ese evento pinch?

Gracias.

Comment: dos cosas, mejora tu pregunta su contenido es muy pobre y no segundo las preguntas van en español, pues estas en SO en español de lo contrario terminará cerrada, pues no es solo poner la pregunta; debes mostrar que has intentado, revisa [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Tal vez te refieras al viewport de tu página, si es el caso, agrega lo sig. dentro del head

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```